SSJS GET Image request retrieving different data than Postman
Using a SSJS GET on an endpoint which returns binary image data results in different data than the same call in Postman. Here's my setup:
var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value";
var headerNames = ["Accept", "Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["image/jpeg; charset=utf-8", "Bearer "+access];
var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
var encoded = Base64Encode(response.Content);
Variable.SetValue("response",encoded);

Which returns:
w7/DmMO/w6AAEEpGSUYAAQEBAGAAYAA...
This does not result in a successful image when added to
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,w7/DmMO/w6...
However, the same call in Postman returns the successful image and the output is different:
..."data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAY
Interestingly, decoding both outputs results in some telling patterns:
Broken SSJS Output Decode:
...%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©...
Working Postman Output Decode:
...%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������...
Presumably there are some character encoding differences that manifest here.
Any ideas on how to get to the bottom of this?
